# getting matplotlib figure to update with new data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have the code below which is reading data out of a csv file and creating a graph using matplotlib. The csv file being used updates periodically, and the graph updates to reflect this.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

objects = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")

def update_graph():
    fig.clear()
    cols = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/user/Dropbox/sent_proj/live_info.csv",header=None,  names=cols,encoding = "UTF-8",low_memory=False)
    performance = df.values.tolist()
    flat_list = [int(item) for sublist in performance for item in sublist]
    a = np.array(flat_list)
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    mask1 = a < 0
    mask2 = a >= 0
    plt.axhline(0, color='black')
    plt.bar(y_pos[mask1], a[mask1], align='center', color = 'r', width= 1, edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 1)
    plt.bar(y_pos[mask2], a[mask2], align='center', color = 'g', width= 1, edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 1)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    win.after(20000, update_graph)

fig = plt.figure()
win = fig.canvas.manager.window
win.after(100, update_graph)
plt.show()
```

I wanted to add to this by being able to click on the graph and display some data which I was able to get to work by adapting some code I found. The issue is I cannot get it to update any longer. Currently I get an error about the figure.

win = fig.canvas.manager.window

AttributeError: 'FigureManagerInterAgg' object has no attribute 'window'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

objects = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")

def update_graph():
    fig.clear()
    cols = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    df = pd.read_csv("live_info.csv", header=None, names=cols, 
    encoding="UTF-8", low_memory=False)
    performance = df.values.tolist()
    flat_list = [int(item) for sublist in performance for item in sublist]
    a = np.array(flat_list)
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    ax2.axhline(0, color='black')
    mask1 = a < 0
    mask2 = a >= 0
    bars = ax2.bar(y_pos[mask1], a[mask1], align='center', color = 'r', width= 1, edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 1, picker=True)
    bars = ax2.bar(y_pos[mask2], a[mask2], align='center', color = 'g', width= 1, edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 1, picker=True)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    for label in ax2.get_xticklabels():  # make the xtick labels pickable
        label.set_picker(True)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    win.after(20000, update_graph)

def onpick1(event):
    (on mouse click stuff)


fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(1)
win = fig.canvas.manager.window
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
win.after(100, update_graph)
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to get my new code to update in the way my previous one was ? and how can I go about doing this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your solution for updating the graph is backend dependent; it will only work with the TkAgg (or TkCairo) backend. Note the respective lines in the first code that explicitely set this backend. In general I might recommend to use `FuncAnimation` for such purposes, because it is backend independent. Finally note, that all of this might simply fail, because you use PyCharm (because I'm not sure the PyCharm backend is interactive at all).

Comment: Thats not an issue for me at this point, im just trying to get it to update right now regardless of backend

Comment: For a solution that works "regardless of backend" I would recommend using a `FuncAnimation` as commented above.